# UTF8 checkmark in shell prompt

Tags: bash, zsh, prompt

I'm trying to get a green checkmark (when the last command finished successfully) in my Bash and Zsh prompts:

```
PS1='\[\033]0;$PWD\007\]\n\
$(st=$?; if [[ $st -eq 0 ]]; then printf "\[\033[01;32m\]\u2713"; else printf "\[\033[01;31m\]$BEL$st"; fi) \
\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h\
\[\033[01;30m\]:\
\[\033[;;33m\]\w\
\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\n\
\[\033[35m\]$\[\033[0m\] '
```

(for Bash)

```
PROMPT="
%B%(?.%F{green}\u2713.%F{red}$(tput bel)%?)%f%b %F{green}%n@%m%F{black}%B:%b%F{yellow}%~ %f\$vcs_info_msg_0_
%F{magenta}%(!.#.$)%f "
```

(for Zsh)

but that does not work: I see the code written in the prompt (u2713), not interpreted as an UTF-8 char (for the check mark, here)...

Can you help me out?

Comment: For bash, use \\u2713.

Comment: That's what is in my Bash prompt...

Comment: Try `PROMPT="%B%(?.%F{green}"$'\u2713'".%F{red}$(tput bel)%?)%f%b %F{green}%n@%m%F{black}%B:%b%F{yellow}%~ %f\$vcs_info_msg_0_%F{magenta}%(!.#.$)%f "`

Comment: @user3341592: No, you have just a single backslash, use two of them.

Comment: @LéaGris, please submit your answer. You both have answered successfully my demand!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @choroba, same thing: correct answer!

Comment: That's why you shouldn't ask two questions at the same time ;-)

Comment: I wanted to show I worked on them already a lot, before firing a question. But you're right… (Submit an answer, btw).